# Web site fails to start when trying to use shadow copy, no useful info in the event log

Tags: iis, asp.net, shadow-copies

I have an ASP.NET Blazor web site, using .NET7 running on Windows Server 2022/IIS 10.

Due to [some problems I'm having with uploads](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146630/iis-locking-files-even-when-there-is-an-app-offline-htm-present), I decided to try enabling shadow copy, as this is supposed to avoid this problem.

I followed the info on [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Nov/07/Avoid-WebDeploy-Locking-Errors-to-IIS-with-Shadow-Copy-for-ASPNET-Core-Apps), and changed my `Web.config` file to look like this...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"
      encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <location path="."
            inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore"
             path="*"
             verb="*"
             modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"
             resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
                  arguments=".\MyWebSite.dll"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="inprocess">
        <handlerSettings>
          <handlerSetting name="enableShadowCopy"
                          value="true" />
          <handlerSetting name="shadowCopyDirectory"
                          value="../_ShadowCopyDirectory/" />
        </handlerSettings>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

However, this results in the web site not starting, and a 500 being returned. If I comment out or remove the `<handlerSettings>` section, the site works fine.

Looking in the server event log shows an entry with a source of `IIS AspNetCore Module V2` and the following description...

> Could not load configuration. Exception message:

That's it, the total message.

It looks to me as if IIS isn't managing to read the config file, which would usually be because the XML is invalid, but I've checked it in a validator, and came out OK.

Although I don't think it's getting that far, the `_ShadowCopyDirectory` folder exists, so that's not the problem. I've enabled parent paths, so that shouldn't be it either, although as I said, my suspicion is that it's not even getting that far.

The site in question is using .NET 7, which supports this feature, so that shouldn't be the issue either. I checked the IIS logs, but they don't show anything for the times it failed to load.

Anyone any idea what might be going wrong, or where I might look for more information? The event log was no help.

Comment: Depending on your IIS configuration, `../_ShadowCopyDirectory/` can be a very bad place to put the files. So it might work for that blog author, but fail on yours. Did you try to use another folder (such as `C:\shadow`) instead?

Comment: @LexLi I chose that location, as I have write access to it. I doubt very much that I would have access to `C:\` at all. However, judging by the paltry event log entry, it looked like the issue was reading the config file itself. Would I get such an error if the problem was the folder? Thanks for the comment

Comment: `I doubt very much that I would have access to `C:` at all.` are you able to list shadow copies or create a test shadow copy? https://superuser.com/a/1067040/31845

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks, but I don't have that sort of access to the server. I only have a control panel, so can' get at a command prompt.

Comment: Does it work on test environment? If so, it is probably a configuration/limitation that needs to be addressed by the system admin.

Comment: @GregAskew Not sure what you mean by test environment. I'm doing all of this on a test site rather than a live one, but all my sites are under the same hosting. I have checked all the config settings that I have in my control panel, but can't see anything that helps

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User

Comment: Shared hosting environments with "control panels" usually have limitations that are unknown and cannot be overcome. Shadow copies could be disabled or something similar.. Given that this is a relatively recently introduced feature and is obscure, you should consider one of the other solutions that exists.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel The thread saved my life indeed. Giving rights to the ShadowCopies folder fixes it. Too bad the error message is so non-functional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, fixed by deleting web.config and re-uploading. Simply overwriting it didn't help.